# Xamarin MVVMCross - Binding on a Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I´m trying to use MvvmCross binding inside a Google Maps InfoWindow, on Android. I have a MvxFragment with a MapFragment inside.
I created a custom xml layout for the InfoWindow and tried to use a MvxFrameControl to display it, like this:

```
public class InfoWindow : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
{
    private readonly BaseStateFragment _window;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Restaurant> _restaurants;

    public InfoWindow(BaseStateFragment window, Dictionary<string, Restaurant> restaurants)
    {
        _window = window;
        _restaurants = restaurants;
    }
    public View GetInfoContents(Marker p0)
    {
        var layoutContainer = new MvxFrameControl(Resource.Layout.fragment_home_map_info, _window.Context, null)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent),
            DataContext = _restaurants[p0.Id] //ViewModel
        };

        return layoutContainer;
    }

    public View GetInfoWindow(Marker p0)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

When I click on the marker, the method GetInfoContents is called but nothing is happening (the event binding is ok, I got it to work without binding).

Any ideas ?

As Requested, the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_item"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        layout="@layout/item_list_restaurant" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_open_restaurant"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_go_restaurant_page"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFacebook"
        android:background="@color/lightBlue"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show `fragment_home_map_info.axml` ??

Comment: Sure! Xml included.

Comment: Hmm can't spot anything except `orientation` doesn't exist in Framelayout. Do you have a minimal example somewhere?